# Netsuite - Multiple Page Forms / Multi Step Forms

Tags: javascript, django, netsuite, hubspot

Is there a way to setup multiple paged form in Netsuite (or Hubspot) or somehow reorganize it custom after integration in a website. Not a problem if the page is updating or fetching the next field element. The most important is the multi-page structure (as a kind of quiz card) and the completeness of the arranged data. Working on django/js, kind of PRG pattern.

Have tried to use the pagination libraries or sliders to give that effect through putting the timeout after the form mounting. Didn't really work.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4325849970.html#serverWidget.Assistant